# Can not set lxc.apparmor.profile

Tags: lxc, apparmor

I can not disable apparmor for lxc container:

```
$ lxc launch images:centos/7 a1
Creating a1
Starting a1
$ lxc config set a1 lxc.apparmor.profile unconfined
Error: Invalid config: Unknown configuration key: lxc.apparmor.profile
$ lxc --version
3.0.3
```

What's wrong and how to set property ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an LXC setting for an LXD container. So it should be set as:

```
lxc config set a1 raw.lxc "lxc.apparmor.profile=unconfined"
```

or the previous property before version 3:

```
lxc config set a1 raw.lxc "lxc.aa_profile=unconfined"
```

Comment: This answer does the job! Then why not accepted?